# CodeIgniter image manip. script mixing up file names

Tags: codeigniter, image-manipulation

This is from a CodeIgniter application that uses its image manipulation library.

`$photos` contains an array of relative photo paths. This script should resize the original and also create a medium (_m) and small (_s) size.

When I only send one photo to the script, everything works great.

When I send a second, things get screwed up - the first image works fine, but then:

-The original second image isn't resized at all (should be resized to 800 wide/high)
-The "original" second image size (800x800) is named as a small image with the *first* image's file name.

```
foreach($photos as $photo) {
  $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
  $config['source_image']  = $photo;
  $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;

  $photoparts = pathinfo($photo);

  // Resize Original
  $config['width']   = 800;
  $config['height']  = 800;
  $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
  $this->image_lib->resize();

  // Medium Size
  $config['width']   = 500;
  $config['height']  = 500;
  $config['new_image'] = $photoparts['dirname'].'/'.$photoparts['filename'].'_m.'.$photoparts['extension'];
  $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
  $this->image_lib->resize();

  // Small Size
  $config['width']   = 200;
  $config['height']  = 200;
  $config['new_image'] = $photoparts['dirname'].'/'.$photoparts['filename'].'_s.'.$photoparts['extension'];
  $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
  $this->image_lib->resize();
}
```

I can't figure out for the life of me why the file names are getting mixed up. The only thing I can think of is that I'm doing this all on a local server, so maybe it's running so fast that the script gets ahead of itself? I doubt that's the case, though.

Comment: I'm sorry but could you explain more clearly what would you like this code to do?I really don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out - I guess the fact that I was modifying the original source image before the others was creating problems, so when I moved that part to the end, everything works fine.